# Zend2 Hostname router constraint

Tags: php, regex, routes, zend-framework2

I have a typical hostname router as follows :

```
$route = Hostname::factory(array(
    'route' => ':subdomain.domain.tld',
    'constraints' => array(
        'subdomain' => '??regex??',
    )
));
```

The problem is that I want to match all the subdomains except 'www'.In other words this router should handle all the subdomains but www.domain.tld. I tried different regex solutions without success. What's the right regex to achieve this ?

Some of the regex solutions I used :

- '/[^www]/'
- '^.*(?< !^www)\$'
- '^(?!(www)$)'

Comment: `I tried different regex solutions without success. ` Post them..

Comment: try this `'^(?!www).*'` . It won't allow `www` at the start. `^(?!.*www)` won't allow `www` at the start or end or at the middle.

Comment: '^(?!www).*' this worked fine ! (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the below regex.

```
'^(?!www).*'
```

This won't allow `www` at the start.